# Test for "cyclicality" in time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

Is there a good test for "cyclicality" in time series data, hopefully that is pre-built into a Python stats package or easy to write?  I'm not looking for stationarity alone, because that would also test positive for random dispersion around a mean.  I'm also not looking for autocorrelation alone, as I'm looking for a solution that works when the lags are variable (instead of a predictable cycle e.g. every year).

For instance, look at the linked image below. There is:

1. Autocorrelation from each smallest step to the next.
2. Stationarity around the mean of the overall data set
3. Trend (autocorrelation of the rate of change) from each smallest step to the next.  However, this is stochastically bounded by the overall data set's stationarity

Alternatively, the above could also be described as autocorrelation with a stochastic amount of lag that is itself autocorrelated.

Given how often this occurs in time series data, I thought there might be something off-the-shelf.

https://marketrealist.imgix.net/uploads/2016/03/joy-china.jpg?w=660&fit=max&auto=format

Comment: Would "cyclicality" mean "seasonality"?  And could you explain what you mean by "variable" lags?  What could it possibly mean to be cyclical or seasonal when there isn't a well-defined period?

Comment: Cyclicality is a vague term so I tried to define what I meant specifically.  Seasonality would be cyclicality on a well-defined annual period.  In both the hard/soft sciences, you often see cyclicality without well-defined periods - each "cycle" has a different length, but still exhibits the three characteristics I described above.  Think about the macroeconomic cycle, where the length of uptrends and recessions are quite variable, especially recently.

Comment: The problem is that your concept of "cyclicality" is not clearly formed, nor is it quantitative.  As it stands, virtually any dataset that swings up and down could be considered "cyclical."  This makes the concept not subject to rigorous analysis.  To create an answerable question, you really need to describe "cyclicality" much more clearly and definitely.  It is possible you might find some inspiration in threads about "dynamic time warping."

Comment: I think bamboo is just describing some sort of mean reverting process (?)